# Send one SMS to Multiple phone numbers

Tags: java, android

I have an `arraylist` of **phone numbers**. When I send a message it only sends to the last number on the list. Here is my code.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == CONTACT_PICK_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        ArrayList<Contact> selectedContacts = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra("SelectedContacts");

        String display="";
        for(int i=0;i<selectedContacts.size();i++){
            display += (i+1)+"   "+selectedContacts.get(i).toString()+"\n";
            theNumber=selectedContacts.get(i).phone;
        }
        contactsDisplay.setText("Selected Contacts : \n\n"+display);
    }
}

protected void sendMsg(String theNumber, String myMsg) {
    String SENT = "Message Sent";
    String DELIVERED = "Message Delivered";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS SENT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Generic Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }

        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(theNumber, null, myMsg, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}
```

Comment: That code isn't calling `sendMsg()` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is simply replacing the numbers from the list to `theNumber` variable.

```
theNumber=selectedContacts.get(i).phone;
```

When the loop ends, it finds the variable `theNumber` updated with last number from the list.

Comment: im sorry. im really at lost here. im new to android programming. what can i do?

Comment: I Think you're new to writing code. 
Call the 
`sendMsg(theNumber,<Replace this with you're message to be sent in String>);` inside the loop after the number gets assigned to the 'the Number' variable.